# How do I run daphne (or any python application) from a no-login user?

Tags: server, permissions, python3, services, django

## Bottom Line Up Front

For security, I want a "your only purpose in life is to serve butter" user with only enough privileges to execute Daphne and my Django app as a systemd service. How do I make Daphne executable by my single-purpose user?

## Background

I'm getting ready to deploy a Django app I created. The app is installed on a remote headless Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server, which I `ssh` into. I can run the app just fine as the user that I log in as, but I'd like to create a daemon to run in the background under a different user and group made specifically for my Django app.

I have created a user called `daphne-service-user` using this command:

```
sudo useradd -d /srv/my-django-app -rU daphne-service-user
```

I then went and edited `/etc/passwd` so that the entry ends in `/usr/sbin/nologin` so that `daphne-service-user` can't login.

I created a `systemd` service file for my application with user and group set to `daphne-service-user`. When I tried to run my service, it failed. `systemctl status` showed:

```
Aug 23 06:06:25 tiny-server systemd[1]: daphne.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 23 06:06:25 tiny-server systemd[1]: Stopped Daphne server for MyApp.
Aug 23 06:06:25 tiny-server systemd[1]: daphne.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 23 06:06:25 tiny-server systemd[1]: daphne.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 23 06:06:25 tiny-server systemd[1]: Failed to start Daphne server for MyApp.
```

After some troubleshooting, I figured out that if I switched the user and group in the service file to my regular logged in user, the service runs just fine, no problems. I've tried:

- using `sudo chown daphne-service-user:daphne-service-user /home/myaccount/.local/bin/daphne`
- creating a symbolic link in `/usr/bin`
- changing ownership of the symbolic link I copied into `/usr/bin`